# AIDE --into return code 18

Tags: apt, software-installation

I've been trying absolutely everything to fix this issue with "aide" so I did an `apt-get update && apt get autoclean` before installing `apt-get install aide`, but the thing is every time I want to run `aide --init` or `aideinit` it returns an error

`couldn't open the file var/lib/aide/ please don't call aid without parameters/aide.db.new for writing`

I did a `apt-get install --reinstall aide`

I've tried

```
sudo touch/var/lib/aide.db
Sudo chmod 600 /var/lib/aide/aide.db
Sudo aide --config=/use/share/aide/config/aide/aide.conf --check
```

Because I was originally missing the `.db` file

I can not find a solution anywhere, so I uninstalled aide, I cleaned the system and reinstalled it and now there is no `aide.conf` file and no `aide.db` file.

Is this program completely corrupt or am I missing something on the whole `sudo apt-get install aide` syntax?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1096333.html

Answer (score 0):

I did install these packages

```
sudo apt-get install gcc byacc 
Sudo apt-get install flex
Sudo apt-get install  bison
Sudo apt-get install libmhash2 libmhash-dev
Sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-8.3
Sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
Sudo apt-get install libpng-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Then I was able to take the AIDE-0.16 file and ran these commands

```
tar xvzf aide-0.16.tar.gz
./configure
make
make install
cp /etc/aide/aide.conf/ /usr/share/etc/aide.conf/
Mv /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new/ /var/lib/aide/aide.db/
Sudo aide
Sudo aide --Init
Sudo aide --check 
Reboot
```

Comment: Please edit you question. Use code tags instead of that horrible bold and also add what you just commented.

Comment: @hellomoto Check the edit history [here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/846115/revisions) and add any helpful info not in the answer by [editing it](http://askubuntu.com/posts/846115/edit).

Comment: How did you mark those grey area's  anwar ?